# Y is not incremented

Tags: c

This is the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>  

void main() {
    int *x,*y;
    int a=23,b=56;

    x=&a;
    y=&b;

    printf("%d\t%d",x,y);

    x++;
    y++;

    /* here only x is incremented but y remains same. What is the reason? */
    printf("\n%d\t%d",x,y);
}
```

i.e x is incremented by 2.But y remains as it is. How?

Comment: Did you consider indenting your code? While it doesn't really matter for this code since it would have just one indentation depth, it's a good practice to do it anyway.

Comment: x incremented by 2? What is your platform and compiler? Some microcontroller?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  What output are you seeing?

Comment: It's %p for pointers, not %d.

Comment: what I wouldn't understand is how you would get the expected results, as your increment would move your pointer by 1 into the memory. the given results would be random at best.

Comment: @ Michael Burr 8674 9287 ,8676 9287  the later values point to the incremented values

Comment: @ dvhh i have tried on 2 different platforms

Comment: Why on earth you want to use turbo C and that too on a win 7 ? Its a very old compiler.

Comment: Win 7 and Turbo C. That's like trying to genetically engineer a cross between Mr Spock and a trilobite :-) Seriously, get a decent compiler if you can. GCC has Windows ports and even MS gives away their express edition. I realise that may not be possible as, for some ungodly reason, Indian universities seem hell-bent on churning out sub-par coders with experience only in dead compilers that the standards have left behind. They're really not doing anyone _any_ favours there.

Comment: @paxdiablo: sad but true - and it's not just the prehistoric compilers - the teaching is all based on some truly awful books from the Turbo C era (1980s) - Kanetkar seems to be the worst offender (Let Us C, etc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is *no* guarantee that your pointers are the same size as your integers so you realy shouldn't be using `%d` as the format specifier.

I've seen problems similar to this when people pass `long` variables to `printf` with a specifier for an `int`. Because the long was wider than the `int`, it confused `printf` regarding where things were on the stack.

You should be using `%p` for pointers. There are also numerous other problems with that code, standards-wise. Try the following as a starting point:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int *x, *y;
    int a = 23, b = 56;

    x=&a; y=&b;
    printf ("%p  %p\n", x, y);

    x++; y++;
    printf ("%p  %p\n", x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's one *possible* explanation (thanks to the comment from Michael Burr):

Let's say your pointer are 32 bits and your integers are 16 bits and that you are on a little-endian architecture (like Intel).

Further, assume the address of `a` is `0x12345678` and the address of `b` is `0x1234567a`.

When you pass them to `printf`, you push two 32-bit values on the stack but `printf` only reads two 16-bit values since it's been told that with the `%d %d` format specifiers:

```
       himem
      --------
    / | 0x12 |
push  | 0x34 |
   |  | 0x56 |
    \ | 0x78 |
      --------
    / | 0x12 | \ printf reads 0x1234
push  | 0x34 | /
   |  | 0x56 | \ printf reads 0x567a
    \ | 0x7a | /
      --------
       lomem
```

Then, when you increment both pointers and call `printf` again, you get:

```
       himem
      --------
    / | 0x12 |
push  | 0x34 |
   |  | 0x56 |
    \ | 0x7a |
      --------
    / | 0x12 | \ printf reads 0x1234
push  | 0x34 | /
   |  | 0x56 | \ printf reads 0x567c
    \ | 0x7c | /
      --------
       lomem
```

So you can see in that scenario why it might look as if only one pointer had been incremented but the real problem is that you're not *printing* the pointers, rather you're printing the most significant half of one of them (which probably won't change) and the least significant half of that same one (which will change).

Comment: I think you hit on it - since he's using Turbo C, I'll bet the `int`'s are 16 bits and the pointers are 32-bit segmented far pointers...

Comment: Turbo C may not understand %p (I don't remember to be honest). But the fact remains: format specifiers MUST match the parameter types so it is definitely wrong to use %d for pointers. If %p is not available typecast may be used: `printf("%u %u", (unsigned)x, (unsigned)y );`

Comment: @ paxdiablo Thank you.But even then, is it possible to print the increments in integer format?

Comment: @Suhail, provided you _understand_ the data layouts, you can. It's not portable but you could try something like: `printf ("0x%04x%04x\n" myTwoIntPointer);`. That way you push 32 bits (the pointer) and print two 16-bit values joined together to look like one.

Answer (score 0):

how about... 
int *x;
int *y;
instead of int *x,*y;

Answer (score 0):

Hi you increment your pointer address not value use `(*x)++ (*y)++`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are accessing a pointer and incrementing a pointer. What you might wanted to do is this:

```
void main() {
  int *x,*y;
  int a=23,b=56;
  x=&a;
  y=&b;
  printf("%d\t%d",*x,*y);
  (*x)++;
  (*y)++;
  printf("\n%d\t%d",*x,*y);
  return 0;
}
```

Notice the (*x)++ and (*y)++ to access the *value* of the pointer, because it is this, you want to increment. If you write x++ or y++ you increment the pointer itself, meaning you push the address on where it is pointing at forward. This leads in your case to undefined values.

Comment: @ Woltan i want to increment the address.

Comment: Oh, ok then never mind the code above ;) Just be careful not to run into not allocated memory since this **could** lead to segmentation faults.

Answer (score 0):

you're incrementing the *pointers*, not the values if that's any help.

I can't tell you more, since that source doesn't actually compile and gives you roughly the same warning I did :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int *x,*y;
        int a=23,b=56;
        x=&a;
        y=&b;
        printf("%d\t\t%d",*x,*y);
        x++;
        y++;
        printf("\n%d\t\t%d",*x,*y);
        return 0;
}
```

that will compile, and shows the contents - on my compiler that results in the following output:

```
23      56
1606415920      23
```

(I put the two '\t' per line to guarantee separation of values, this doesn't affect the rest of the code)

since I *assume* you want the code to increment `a` and `b` the code would be as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int *x,*y;
        int a=23,b=56;
        x=&a;
        y=&b;
        printf("%d\t\t%d",*x,*y);
        (*x)++;
        (*y)++;
        printf("\n%d\t\t%d",*x,*y);
        return 0;
}
```

which prints:

```
23      56
24      57
```

Answer (score 0):

Please the program :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
    int *x= NULL;
    int *y = NULL;
    int a=23,b=56;
    x=&a;
    y=&b;
    printf("%x\t%x",x,y);
    x++;
    y++;
    printf("\n%x\t%x",x,y);
}
```

I beleive it should be fine then.Only the values are intialized properly.

Comment: I fixed your formatting but, honestly, your answer will not make a difference. Whether they're initialised to NULL or not, they're still set before use: `x=&a; y=&b;`.