# if statement problem

Tags: c

see i have one complex code but i m stuck up some where so i m just giving you part of that..

i have one function

```
function(int a,uint64_t b,int c);
```

when i was calling function

```
  uint64_t b;
  int c;

  printf("enter b");
  scanf("%d",&b);  // i m giving 1

   printf("enter c");
   scanf("%d",&c);  // i m giving 2

  function(0xcd32ab00 ,b ,c);
```

in that function definition i m comparing value b with one another parameter like

```
 /*  magicNum is type uint64_t type & it has value 1 */
if(magicNum == b) 
{
 // do something
}
```

But that "do something"  does not happen;
when i m printing magicNum & b both have value 1 so can not understand why this happen.

when i write

```
if((uint64_t)magicNum == (uint64_t)b) 
{
 // do something
}
```

this works perfectly.

i know i m doing one silly mistake but i m not getting...plz help me...
i m working on 32 bit linux system

Comment: make sure you didn't mistype `=` instead of `==`

Comment: @Gregory: it would work even if he mistyped it since the value of b is not zero

Comment: Don't make us guess what your code _really_ looks like - post it! How do I know you haven't posted the real code? It's the semicolon in the prototype. Post the smallest example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: How are you printing the values of `magicNum` and `b`?

Comment: @Keith Thompson  both using as  %d

Comment: `"%d"` expects an `int` argument; you're giving it a `uint64_t` argument.  Among other possibilities, if `int` is 32 bits, it might be discarding the high-order 32 bits.  Try `printf("%llu %llu\n", (unsigned long long)magicNum, (unsigned long long)b);`.

Comment: okey Keith Thompson  i get it...

Comment: @Mr.3: You need to use the `@` character if you want me to be notified that you've followed up on my comment (I happened to see it anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was something wrong with your original code that you didn't show us. That's because the following works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void fn (int a, uint64_t b, int c) {
    uint64_t magicNum = 1;
    if (magicNum == b)
        puts ("They match!");
    if ((uint64_t)magicNum == (uint64_t)b)
        puts ("They still match!");
}

int main (void) {

    fn (0xcd32ab00 ,1 ,2);
    return 0;
}
```

outputting:

```
They match!
They still match!
```

Based on your update that you're using `scanf("%d")` to get the values, this is a fairly well known problem to those of us that have been warped from decades of C usage :-)

When you provide `%d` as a format specifier, it expects a pointer to an `int` type, and it will write to that type. If the pointer you give it is to a type twice as wide (say 64 bits instead of 32), it will only write to *half* of it.

You can see this here:

```
int main (void) {
    uint64_t x = 0xffffffffffffffffULL;
    printf ("Enter your number: ");
    scanf ("%d", &x);     // signed int
    printf ("%llu\n", x); // unsigned long long
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs `-4294967295` when you enter `1` (because it hasn't touched the other half of the variable, which is still full of 1-bits).

If you change the `scanf` format string to use `%llu`, it works fine.

Keep in mind that this is only because my `unsigned long long` values are 64 bits wide, just like my `unit64_t` ones. For portability, you *should* be using the format specifier macros located in `inttypes.h`. For `uint64_t`, the correct one would be `SCNu64`. The macro names are formed by using:

- `PRI` for `printf` format strings or `SCN` for `scanf` format strings.
- `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x` or `X` to specify signed decimal (`d` and `i`), unsigned octal, unsigned decimal, unsigned lower-case hex and unsigned upper-case hex.
- optional `LEAST`, `FAST`, `MAX` or `PTR` for different variable types.
- `N` which is the bit size.

`SCNu64` expands to `"llu"` on my implementation but that's not necessarily the case everywhere. On a system that had 64 bit `int` and 256-bit `long long`, it would most likely be `"u"` (since it equates to an `unsigned int`).

Sample code showing how to use these format strings is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main (void) {
    uint64_t x = 0xffffffffffffffffULL;
    printf ("Enter your number: ");
    scanf ("%" SCNu64, &x);
    printf ("%" PRIu64 "\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

---

As to why your `printf` may print out the reduced value, see this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main (void) {
    uint64_t x = 0xffffffffffffffffULL;
    printf ("Enter your number: ");
    scanf ("%u", &x);
    printf ("uint64_t = %" PRIu64 "\n", x);
    printf ("uint64_t = %" PRIu64 " (when and'ed)\n", x & 0xffffffffU);
    printf ("uint     = %u\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
Enter your number: 5
uint64_t = 18446744069414584325
uint64_t = 5 (when and'ed)
uint     = 5
```

I suspect you're printing it with the lower-size format string as well. When you do that, it's actually an alignment problem. Because your processor is little-endian, it works by accident (the first 32 bits of a 64 bit value are the least significant bits, the `5` in the example above).

But it will stuff up any arguments *after* that point in your printf because you've pushed 64 bits onto the stack and `printf` only consumes 32, hence the misalignment.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468580/y-is-not-incremented/5468657#5468657) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424528/printf-of-a-size-t-variable-with-lld-ld-and-d-type-identifiers/2424554#2424554) for earlier answers explaining how this works (or, more correctly, doesn't work).

Comment: fn (0xcd32ab00 ,1 ,2);
 here dont put 1 & 2 directly scan both value as i have did...        printf("enter b");
              scanf("%d",&b);  // i m giving 1

   printf("enter c");
   scanf("%d",&c);  // i m giving 2

Comment: oh man while scanning when i have written %lld  it starts to work....thank you paxdiablo ..... but still scaning with %d its print proper value then why this problem occur..?? can you explain it..??

Comment: @Mr.32 : I've added a possible explanation for this, see the bit tacked on the end.

Answer (score 2):

arguments a and b swapped ??

```
 function(0xcd32ab00 ,1 ,2);
```

should be

```
 function(1, 0xcd32ab00 ,2);
```

Comment: no, everything is ok. /*  magicNum is type uint64_t type & it has value 1 */ he is trying to compare 1 with 1 but initialy first operand is of int32 type